# Python reading XML files keeps getting error "list index out of range"

Tags: python, xml, list, dom

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<Thread THREAD_SEQUENCE="Q268_R16">
<RelQuestion RELQ_ID="Q268_R16">
<RelQSubject>Best Bank.</RelQSubject>
<RelQBody>Hi ti all QL's; What bank you are using? and why? Are you using this bank just because it has an affiliate at home? Regards;</RelQBody>
</RelQuestion>
</Thread>
```

In the XML file, there are 244 RelQBody tags.
What I want to do is getting the text inside the RelQBody tag. I have tried something like this:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")
data = dom.documentElement

question = data.getElementsByTagName("RelQBody")
i=1
for q in question:
    print("%i. %s" % (i, q.childNodes[0].data))
    i = i+1
```

But i keep getting an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\python\test.py", line 13, in <module>
  print("%i. %s" % (i, q.childNodes[0].data))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, when i tried this code:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")
data = dom.documentElement

question = data.getElementsByTagName("RelQBody")
i=1
for q in question:
    print("%i" % i)
    i = i+1
```

i got number 1-244. it is exactly the same as in the dataset.

So why there's a difference when i print out with the string and without the string? Maybe someone can tell me which part did i do wrong?
I'm new to Python so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.dom.minidom
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")
data = dom.documentElement

question = data.getElementsByTagName("RelQBody")
for i,q in enumerate(question):
    if len(q.childNodes) > 0:
        print("%i. %s" % (i+1, q.childNodes[0].data))
```

Comment: Further question. In case of empty RelQBody tags, i want to use the text inside RelQSubject as the question. I create a code like this:
    for i in range(len(qbody)):
    if len(qbody[i].childNodes) > 0:
      question.append(qbody[i].childNodes[0].data.lower())
    else:
      question.append(qsubject[i].childNodes[0].data.lower())

is there any way better to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 1):

i'm guessing the blame is `childNodes[0]`, because maybe one of the nodes has 0 children, and calling `childNodes[0]` will result in IndexError

So try this:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parse("test.xml")
data = dom.documentElement

question = data.getElementsByTagName("RelQBody")
i=1
for q in question:
    if len(q.childNodes) > 0:
        print("%i. %s" % (i, q.childNodes[0].data))
    i = i+1
```

Comment: i just look further down the XML, and yes.. there are 2 threads with empty RelQBody. I guess i have more work to be done in preprocessing this file lol